# sequelize get error when defining association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2, sequelize-cli

im trying to define sequelize association but get error when defining hasMany relationship

`error throw new Error(${this.name}.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model);`

its one to many relationship between account and account_type where

1. `account_type has many account`
2. `account belongs to account_type`

here's my code

**models/account.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../helper/dbConnection');

const accountType = require('./accountType');

const account = sequelize.define('account', {
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: Sequelize. INTEGER,
  },
  account: {
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  nominal: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
  }, 
  description: {
    allowNull: true,
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
  }, 
  type_id: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: 'account_type',
      key: 'id'
    },
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
    onDelete: 'cascade'
  },
  is_deleted: {
    allowNull: false,
    default: false,
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  },
  created_at: Sequelize.DATE,
  updated_at: Sequelize.DATE,
});

account.belongsTo(accountType, { foreignKey: 'type_id' });

module.exports = account;
```

**models/accountType.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../helper/dbConnection');

const account = require('./account');

const accountType = sequelize.define('account_type', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  type: {
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  description: {
    allowNull: true,
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
  parent_id: {
    allowNull: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: 'account_type',
      key: 'id'
    },
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
    onDelete: 'cascade'
  },
  created_at: Sequelize.DATE,
  updated_at: Sequelize.DATE,
});

accountType.hasMany(account);

module.exports = accountType;
```

im already trying follow the documentation but get error instead, im really stuck, please help me anyone

Comment: It's not ideal having a circular dependency like that. account requires accountType which requires account which requires accountType...

Comment: ah thank you very much sir, now i know the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to sir [ankh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2043204/ankh), this code is have circular dependency problem

the solution is just **define the association in 1 file**, either in `models/account.js` or `models/accountType.js`